# How to Display posts thumbnail in dashboard all posts row in first column?

Tags: dashboard

I use the below code . But the code display Thumbnail in the five number column. How to move it first column position?

```
//show Thumbnail in dashboard
function my_function_admin_bar(){ return false; }
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'my_function_admin_bar');

add_image_size( 'admin-list-thumb', 80, 80, false );

add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'tcb_add_post_thumbnail_column', 1);
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'tcb_add_post_thumbnail_column', 1);

function tcb_add_post_thumbnail_column($cols){
$cols['tcb_post_thumb'] = __('Thumbnail');
return $cols;
}

add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'tcb_display_post_thumbnail_column', 1, 2);
add_action('manage_pages_custom_column', 'tcb_display_post_thumbnail_column', 1, 2);

function tcb_display_post_thumbnail_column($col, $id){
switch($col){
case 'tcb_post_thumb':
if( function_exists('the_post_thumbnail') )
echo the_post_thumbnail( 'admin-list-thumb' );
else
echo 'Not supported in theme';
break;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you read this post - http://wpengineer.com/1960/display-post-thumbnail-post-page-overview/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add featured image thumbnail in post column with this code.

Copied from here [Add Featured Post Thumbnails to WordPress Admin Post Columns](http://wpcodesnippet.com/add-featured-post-thumbnails-to-post-columns/).
Haven't tried it myself but it must work.

```
add_image_size( 'admin-list-thumb', 80, 80, false );

// add featured thumbnail to admin post columns
function wpcs_add_thumbnail_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns = array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'featured_thumb' => 'Thumbnail',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'author' => 'Author',
        'categories' => 'Categories',
        'tags' => 'Tags',
        'comments' => '<span class="vers"><div title="Comments" class="comment-grey-bubble"></div></span>',
        'date' => 'Date'
    );
    return $columns;
}

function wpcs_add_thumbnail_columns_data( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
    case 'featured_thumb':
        echo '<a href="' . get_edit_post_link() . '">';
        echo the_post_thumbnail( 'admin-list-thumb' );
        echo '</a>';
        break;
    }
}

if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns' , 'wpcs_add_thumbnail_columns' );
    add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'wpcs_add_thumbnail_columns_data', 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'manage_pages_columns' , 'wpcs_add_thumbnail_columns' );
    add_action( 'manage_pages_custom_column' , 'wpcs_add_thumbnail_columns_data', 10, 2 );
}
```

**EDIT**

Just tried it and it's working fine.

Although it works fine out of the box but you can change thumbnail size in above code if you want to use your custom defined image size.

**EDIT**

Just fixed this code for 80x80 thumbnail.

Comment: Tanks Nike. But how to change Thumbnail Size ?

Comment: Use updated code. I have fixed the code for 80x80 thumbnail.

Comment: VERY NICE BROTHER.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly cleaner version of the code posted by [Nick](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/65003/nick). A couple of differences:

- I'm using anonymous functions to avoid cluttering the global namespace. Note that if you only need to add the code to a single post type, you can also use a closure:

```php
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', function() {
    // Do your thing here
});
```

- Instead of returning a completely new `$columns` array, i'm adding the column in the existing array. If another column is added (either by a WordPress update or another piece of code), this method won't break that.
- A simple `if` in the `manage_posts_custom_column` hook instead of a `switch` seems to make more sense here.

```php
add_image_size("admin-list-thumb", 80, 80, false);

$cols_fn = function($cols) {
    $col_position = 1; // Change this to another position if you want

    return array_merge(
        array_splice($cols, 0, $col_position),
        ["admin-thumb" => "Thumb"],
        $cols
    );
};

$custom_cols_fn = function($col, $id) {
    if ($col == "admin-thumb") {
        $link = get_edit_post_link();
        $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($id, "admin-list-thumb");
        echo $thumb ? "<a href='$link'>$thumb</a>" : "—";
    }
};

add_filter('manage_posts_columns', $cols_fn);
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', $custom_cols_fn, 10, 2 );
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', $cols_fn);
add_action('manage_pages_custom_column', $custom_cols_fn, 10, 2 );
```